# How to access the variables/functions in one notebook into other notebook in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have Configs notebook which has all Sql Connection config like
Connection properties , `jdbcUrl`, username and all...

Now When i use

```
dbutils.run.notebook("/Configs",120)
```

in another Notebook , Its throwing error at
`spark.read.jdbc()` like

```
jdbcurl,connnectionproperties not declared .
```

How to access them into my current notebook ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other method to call the notebook is

```
%run <databricks_notebookpath>
```

Comment: Am asking even though I do that ,the values of Connection properties , jdbcUrl, username are not passed on to current notebook

Comment: did you check this way? Let me know if the problem still persists

Comment: Oh I thought dbutils.notebook.run and %run Will do the same work .Thanks for the difference

Answer (score 1):

`dbutils.run.notebook` executes notebook as a separate job running on the same cluster. As mentioned in another answer, you need to use `%run` to include declarations of one notebook into another ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#use-run-to-import-a-notebook)).

Here is a [working example](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo/blob/master/unit-tests/test_with_percent_run.py).

Answer (score 0):

use the below magic command, works similar to importing modules in python
`%run <notebook_path>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).